# Default values in constructors of a subclass, to pass onto a superclass?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, superclass

I have a class shape with a constructor that takes (int Sides, Coodinates c, Color co) in its constructor, in the class square I don't want to have "int Sides" in the constructor, how do I do this?

```
//Shape
public Shape(int sides, Coordinates c, Color co) {
    this.sides = sides;
    this.c = c;
    this.co = co;
}

//Square
//Like this is gives me an error saying I need to include sides into my
//constructor. I don't want to request the number of sides when creating
//a square, it will always be 4, how do I do this?
public Square(Coordinates c, Color co, int w, int l) {
    //blah blah
}
```

Would I be correct in assuming I would have to pass the value 4 using super(4, c, co) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Square(Coordinates c, Color co, int w, int l) {
    super(4, c, co);
    this.w = w;
    this.l = l;
}
```

Yes you would be correct. However you also need to assign the values of `w` and `l`.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't type that, haha. Thanks for clearing that up for me :)